# The repository 'https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/oguzhaninan/stacer/ubuntu lunar Release' does not have a Release file

Tags: updates

The repository 'https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/oguzhaninan/stacer/ubuntu lunar Release' does not have a Release file.
can't update
when i type sudo apt update its shows like this
i don't know what to do can u please help me

Answer (score 2):

The PPA does not support Ubuntu 23.04. That's why you get the error.
However, the deafault Ubuntu repositories contain the package.

First, remove the PPA.

```
sudo add-apt-repository --remove ppa:oguzhaninan/stacer
```

Then, run

```
sudo apt update
```

Finally, install stacer from the Ubuntu repositories with

```
sudo apt install stacer
```